# Visual Studio Xamarin - framework only in ios 9.3

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am attempting to generate an ad-hoc ipa for my ios app. I am using Visual Studio 2015 and the latest Xamarin plug in. However on attempting the build I receive the following framework error. Nothing online has helped.

Your application is using the 'HealthKitUI' framework, which isn't included in the iOS SDK you're using to build your app (this framework was introduced in iOS 9.3, while you're building with the iOS 9.2 SDK.) This configuration is only supported with the legacy registrar (pass --registrar:legacy as an additional mtouch argument in your project's iOS Build option to select). Alternatively select a newer SDK in your app's iOS Build options.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In most cases you do not run into this issue because, by default, your project will be using **Link SDK** on device builds (including AdHoc / IPA).

You should first double check your build options. If you're using **Don't link** for device builds then you'll end up with a very large application, possibly over the limits that the app store accepts.

Next you should try to update to the latest Xcode (7.3) which ships with the iOS 9.3 SDK. It's also an Apple requirement (not always enforced) to use the latest stable SDK to submit application to the appstore.

Either options should solve your issue - and it's *uncommon* that either (or both) cannot be used.

Comment: Thanks - this post also helped https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/64154/missing-reference-and-health-kit-error-on-build. Specifically for anyone using Visual Studio Xamarin, you can change the project properties > ios build > linker options to 'Link SDK assemblies only'. The build now works.